Solana-Ethereum bridges
Ethereum uses the secp256k1 public key cryptography and Solana uses the ed25519 public key cryptography.
How is that situation handled in the case of bridges? Let's say that we want to certify a block on Ethereum. That would imply submitting the block and the signatures of the Solana validators.
So, the ed25519 cryptography would have to be computed. However, that costs about 300k of gas for each validator which is very expensive.
How are the Solana/Ethereum bridges built?
